# How to intercept Playwright's Firefox image requests

Tags: firefox, jestjs, e2e-testing, playwright, interception

I recently tried to intercept all image requests following the example in their documentation:

```js
await page.route('**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg}', route => route.abort());

// Abort based on the request type
await page.route('**/*', route => {
  return route.request().resourceType() === 'image' ?
      route.abort() : route.continue();
});
```

But it was not working at all.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing string in the types (or they are outdated in v1.15.1):[image]

When logging `route.request().resourceType()` into console, I noticed there is a `"images"` resource type. So you can easily intercept any images including `"images"` to your check.

For instance you could do like this:

```js
await page.route('**/*', route => {
  return route.request().resourceType().match(/(image)s?/) ?
      route.abort() : route.continue();
});
```